# Sublime Text accessing view file name error

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am new to Python, and Sublime Text plugin development, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. I am using Sublime Text 3. I'm trying to create a plugin that will copy the file name to the clipboard. Can anyone help me understand this python error and/or offer a solution?

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class Filename_to_clipboardCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    sublime.set_clipboard(sublime.View.file_name())
    sublime.message_dialog("The full file path was copied to the clipboard")
```

and the error, when I call the plugin from the console, is:

```
>>> view.run_command('filename_to_clipboard')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 549, in run_
return self.run(edit)
  File "/Users/ivan/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Filename_to_clipboard/filename_to_clipboard.py", line 5, in run
sublime.set_clipboard(sublime.View.file_name())
TypeError: file_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

When I do:

```
sublime.set_clipboard(view.file_name())
```

from the conosole, it works! Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Sublime Text API, but it looks like your problem here is that `file_name()` is an instance method, and `sublime.View` is a class so `sublime.View.file_name()` fails.

In Python, when you call an instance method you are implicitly passing the instance as the first argument, which is why it says you are missing the argument `self`. You could even write the call explicitly. For example, `view.file_name()` could also be written `sublime.View.file_name(view)`, but that's kind of silly.

Good luck with your plugin :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining what was going on here!

Answer (score 2):

Try `self.view.file_name()` rather than `sublime.View.file_name()`. You have a reference to an instance of the view for your TextCommand. It was written for ST2, but you may want to take a look at this tutorial

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin/

Comment: Thank you! This is the actual solution simply stated.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to see all your effort wasted, but this functionality already exists in ST3. If you right-click in the edit area, `Copy File Path` is one of the options on the context menu. To create a keyboard shortcut, open `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User` and add the following item:

```json
{ "keys": ["super+i"], "command": "copy_path" }
```

You can of course change the key binding to whatever you want. If the key bindings file is empty when you open it, just add opening and closing square brackets:

```
[
    { "keys": ["super+i"], "command": "copy_path" }
]
```

However, I still encourage you to learn Python and plugin programming, they're both quite rewarding and great fun! Good luck!

---

#### ***EDIT***

Based on a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680770/sublime-text-accessing-view-file-name-error/18685689?noredirect=1#comment27526309_18685689) by @skuroda, here's how I discovered the command to use:

I already knew there was a `Copy File Path` option in the context menu, but looking through `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default` I couldn't find any shortcuts or macros already assigned to that action, and I didn't know exactly what the command's name was. So, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> to open the console, then ran

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

to have all actions logged to the console. I then right-clicked and selected `Copy File Path`, and

```
command: copy_path
```

showed up, along with a message regarding the mouse's location when the context menu event occurred. I assigned the key combination, ran it, and it worked. To finish up, I run

```
sublime.log_commands(False)
```

so the console doesn't get clogged with unnecessary info, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> again to close the console.

Comment: Good tip, might I also add putting `sublime.log_commands(True)` in the console before running the action so you know what command and arguments to bind to.